# Why are NPC houses halfway built?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I just spawned a new, singleplayer, creative, peaceful world. I looked for an NPC village, and hurrah! After ten seconds, I found one. However, when I came down (I was flying) I noticed how a house looked halfway built. I thought some of the chunks haven't loaded in yet, but it did fully load in! I could even go inside! There were two other houses with the problem. I took two screenshots.

[image: The first unbuilt house.]

Comment: are all npc houses built this way?

Comment: No, just some houses are.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears the chunk loading hit an issue while that chunk was being handled. This can happen the server is dealing with a lot of information within a small period of time. This can happen on servers online and locally hosted servers.

I have highlighted the chunk edges so you can see it easier:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Simple Answer: Because minecraft unsuccessfully loaded that chunk:

The Complex Answer: Minecraft stores "chunks" in a file which gets bigger as you move around, exploring more chunks. In this case, Minecraft didn't manage to load that chunk therefore left it and applied the default to it (Without the village: the plain flatland).

Answer (score -1):

Most likely a generation error.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Frank Yes it does. It's not a particularly detailed answer, but this *is* most likely a generation error of some form.

Comment: @Unionhawk How does that help the asker solve the problem?  So far as I can tell, it doesn't.

Comment: It's not a problem that needs solving. As someone who knows the game, this is a correct and valid answer.

Comment: @Frank the problem isn't solvable. It's a generation error, a fault in the game